# 20th century books on geometry

Tags: geometry, reference-request

I've heard something about the fact of some old geometry textbooks, dated to the beginning of the 20th century approximately, have a structure composed by a problem, the solution and then something like a explanation of why the solution worked. I've heard it in a lecture and the speaker said that these books look like what he called "those French books". I was curious, but I have no idea how search for them. Someone know books with similar structures or even know what books are these?

Answer (score 1):

I've been talking with the speaker since I asked this question and today he gave me an old copy of a French algebra book which has the same scheme the geometry books quoted by him. "*Éléments D'Algèbre*" by M. Bourdon, from 1907. A very interesting book indeed, exactly as he said: a property or problem is presented and worked out in a very straight and clear way.